# Meaning of "holidays of hay"

Tags: meaning, literature

What does this phrase, from Pynchon's novel *Gravity's Rainbow*, mean?

> Schnorp, his hair blown like holidays of hay…

There are no references to "holidays" or "hay" in the preceding several pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a *very* obscure usage. From OED definition #3 for ***holiday***...

> colloq. Naut. *A spot carelessly left uncoated in tarring or painting;* see also quot. [below]
>    1882 F. W. P. Jago Anc. Lang. & Dial. Cornwall,
>    *Holidays, parts left untouched in dusting. ‘Don't leave any holidays.’*

Here's a similar instance in [a short story by William Saroyan](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ml1BAAAAIAAJ&q=%22holidays%20of%20hay%22&dq=%22holidays%20of%20hay%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Qj8yUdjQFeeb1AXw-oHADw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAA)

> *The four of them [ran] across a field among rain-flattened **holidays of hay**.*

To my mind, Pynchon is comparing Schnorp's hair to a little pile of fluff/dried grass/hair such as might be found behind the sofa after a perfunctory cleaning. More specifically, perhaps, ungathered straw in a harvested field (that will be swirled into piles by eddies of wind).

Ultimately of course, this usage *does* derive from the normal sense of "holiday", in that it's a bit left over because someone took a short break while cleaning/painting/tidying up.

Comment: +1 I think you got it right. I certainly had never heard that expression or that definition before.

Comment: @Jim: It's so unusual that I'm not sure if I just have a false memory of having heard it before, but I seemed to have a vague memory of someone using "holidays" to mean bits of dog-hair fluff in the angles between the steps of a staircase. I couldn't find anything in Google Books to substantiate a direct connection between fluff and holidays, but when I checked OED that was good enough for me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: The quote you give is not from Saroyan but from Pynchon, who uses it again in his contribution to the collection of short stories to which you've provided a link.

Comment: @The Frog: I guess that makes it a *very, **very*** obscure usage! I couldn't get at the full text, so I didn't cite [this one](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22unswept+holidays%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which is more obviously "marine/naval"-based anyway. But I do recall that Pynchon is fond of [obscure references](http://www.dh2012.uni-hamburg.de/conference/programme/abstracts/literary-wikis-crowd-sourcing-the-analysis-and-annotation-of-pynchon-eco-and-others/), and I *think* this is a typical example. Whatever - it's probably not a meaningless or trivial choice of words.

Comment: Here's the usage I had found: http://books.google.com/books?id=kegtoeLq1UwC&pg=PA150&dq=%22like+holidays+of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=1tsyUeChJenVyQHw0IGQAg&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22like%20holidays%20of%22&f=false